# Floating point quantization from double to 8bit

Tags: floating-point, rounding, quantization

How can I round a `double precision floating point` to the value that can be stored in a `8bit floating point`?
I'm trying to do it mathematically but I have no idea how to do.

I have an `x` `double` number and I should find the nearest `y` that I can express with `n*2^b` with `n` and `b` integer and `n` in `[-128,127]`. But how can I find the best `n` and  `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved with this algorithm:

```
function y = DoubleTo8bit( x )
s=sign(x);
x=abs(x);

if x==0
    y=0;
    return; 
end
b=floor(log2(x)+1)-8+(s>0);
m=s*round(x/2^b);

y=m*2^b;
end
```